# Generate matrix of vectors from labels for multiclass classification (vectorized)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, octave, linear-algebra

I'm structuring my input for a multiclass classifier (*m* data points, *k* classes). In my input, I have the labels for the training data as integers in a vector **y** (i.e. **y** is *m* dimensional and each entry in **y** is an integer between 1 and *k*).

I'd like to transform this into an *m* x *k* matrix. Each row has 1 at the index corresponding to the label of that data point and 0 otherwise (e.g. if the data point has label 3, the row looks like [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...]).

I can do this by constructing a vector **a** = [1 2 3 4 ... k] and then computing

```
M_ = y*(1./b)
M = M_ .== 1
```

(where `./` is elementwise division and `.==` is elementwise logical equals). This achieves what I want by setting everything in the intermediate matrix that is not exactly 1 to 0.

But this solution seems silly and roundabout. Is there a more direct way that I'm missing?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use division like that, in a situation where it doesn't conceptually make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a label vector `y` such as `[1 2 2 1 3 2 3 1]` and a number of classes `k` such as `3`, you can convert this to a label matrix `Y` as follows.

```
function Y = labelmatrix(y, k)
  m = length(y);
  Y = repmat(y(:),1,k) .== repmat(1:k,m,1);
```

The idea is to perform the following expansions:

```
1 1 1     1 2 3
2 2 2     1 2 3
2 2 2     1 2 3
1 1 1 .== 1 2 3
3 3 3     1 2 3
2 2 2     1 2 3
3 3 3     1 2 3
1 1 1     1 2 3
```

This yields:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use logical arrays:

```
M = [1:k] == y;
```

Comment: By far the cleanest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or just by indexing:

```
%// Dummy code to generate some input data
y = [1 4 3 7 2 1];
m = length(y);
k = max(y);

%// Actual conversion using y elements as index 
M = zeros(m, k);
M(sub2ind(size(M), [1:m], y)) = 1

%// Result
M =
1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: `k = max(y);` is a bad idea. It could be that the largest-number class isn't in the vector `y`.

Comment: Well, it's an easy way to generate input data. Of course the OP knows how many classes there are and won't use the first 3 lines